# converting decimals to base negative-10

Tags: binary, decimal-expansion

I have a decimal (base $10$) number, $44$, and would like to convert it to base $-10$.  I know how to convert 
$$
164_{-10} \mapsto 44_{10},
$$
but not the other way around.

Comment: But decimal and base $10$ are the same. Do you mean hexadecimal?

Comment: no base -10 not 10

Comment: Ahh, I read the $-$ as a grammatical thing, rather than as a math-thing.

Comment: sorry i dont really know how to express base -10 mathematically

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft any ideas???

Comment: I highlighted the base change with subscripts.  Is this what you're asking?

Comment: The last digit should be clear. Every digit before that represents something divisible by $\pm10$, so it must be the remainder modulo $10$, that is, $4$. We are left with $40 = (-4)\cdot (-10)$. $(-4)$ is not an admissible digit, hence we write it as $40 = (6+(-10))\cdot (-10) = 6\cdot (-10) + 1\cdot (-10)^2$, and $44 = 4\cdot (-10)^0 + 6\cdot (-10)^1 + 1\cdot(-10)^2 = 164_{-10}$.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is to simply carry and 'borrow' as needed, keeping track of odd vs. even digit positions.  For your example, $44 = 4\times 10^1+4\times 10^0$.  The ones' digit is clearly the same, so now we can concentrate on the tens' digit.  Since $4=10-6$, we can express $4\times 10^1=40$ by borrowing from (or carrying into) the hundreds' digit; $40 = 4\times 10^1$ $= 10\times 10^1 - 6\times 10^1$ $= 1\times 10^2 - 6\times 10^1$ $= 1\times (-10)^2 + 6\times (-10)^1$; in other words a digit $d\gt 0$ in any 'odd' position (10s, 1000s, etc.) converts to a digit $d'=10-d$ in that position and a carry of $1$ into the next digit up.  This can sometimes lead to a cascading effect of borrows and carries; for instance, imagine trying to convert $N=944_{10} = 9\times 10^2 + 4\times 10^1 + 4\times 10^0$.  The ones' place is trivial, as before; and as before, we borrow/carry from the hundreds' place to invert the teens; $N = 9\times 10^2 + 1\times 10^2 - 6\times 10^1 + 4\times 10^0 = 10\times 10^2 - 6\times 10^1 + 4\times 10^0$.  Now, this would 'carry' into the thousands' place as a positive digit: $N=1\times 10^3-6\times 10^1 + 4\times 10^0$, forcing us to do one more round of borrowing, turning $d=1$ into $10-d'=10-9$ : $N=1\times 10^4 - 9\times 10^3 + 0\times 10^2 - 6\times 10^1 + 4\times 10^0$ $=1\times (-10)^4 + 9\times (-10)^3 + 0\times (-10)^2 + 6\times (-10)^1 + 4\times 10^0$ $= 19064_{-10}$.

Answer (score 0):

You do this as you would any normal base: you divide by -10 repeatedly and take the floor and remainder, except you start out with 44 as negative.
$$\frac{-44}{-10}=4+\frac{4}{10}$$
$$\frac{4}{-10}=-1+\frac{6}{10}$$
$$\frac{-1}{-10}=\frac{1}{10}$$
So you obtain $44_{10}=164_{-10}$